# Classic vs universal Google analytics and loss of historical data

Tags: google-analytics, data

I'm keen to use some of the new features in Google Universal Analytics.
I have an old site though that I don't want to **lose the historical data for**.  The comparisons with historical data are interesting for example.

However Google doesn't appear to allow you to change a property from the classic code to the new code.
Am I missing something?

I'm surprised this isn't a bigger issue for many other users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: Google [just announced the upgrade path to universal analytics](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+GoogleAnalytics/posts/RKtyZXt12MC):

> We just launched the Google Analytics Upgrade Center, an easy, two-step process to upgrade your classic Analytics accounts to Universal Analytics.

From their [upgrade instructions](http://analytics.blogspot.com/2013/10/an-easy-way-to-upgrade-to-universal_23.html):

> Step 1: Transfer your property from Classic to Universal Analytics.
>   We’ve developed a new tool to transfer your properties to Universal Analytics that we will be slowly enabling in the admin section of all accounts. In the coming weeks, look for it in your property settings.
>
> [image]
>
> Step 2: Re-tag with a version of the Universal Analytics tracking code.
>   After completing Step 1, you’ll be able to upgrade your tracking code, too. Use the analytics.js JavaScript library on your websites, and Android or iOS SDK v2.x or higher for your mobile apps.
>
> Our goal is to enable Universal Analytics for all Google Analytics properties. Soon all Google Analytics updates and new features will be built on top of the Universal Analytics infrastructure. To make sure all properties upgrade, Classic Analytics properties that don’t initiate a transfer will be auto-transferred to Universal Analytics in the coming months.

---

<s>Google will support upgrading and migrating data to the universal analytics, but that upgrade process is not ready yet.  From their [help document](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2817075):</s>

> In the coming months, look for documentation to help you upgrade your existing Google Analytics web properties and data to UA.

Comment: Coming months, it was April that they started this.  The coming months have come and gone.  I'm still surprised people aren't complaining about this much more.

Comment: The process is now available.  It was just a matter of days. :-)